# how can i install lite-server? it keeps giving me error

Tags: node.js, npm, solidity

npm ERR! code EACCES
npm ERR! syscall mkdir
npm ERR! path /usr/local/lib/node_modules/lite-server
npm ERR! errno -13
npm ERR! Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lite-server'
npm ERR!  [Error: EACCES: permission denied, mkdir '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lite-server'] {
npm ERR!   errno: -13,
npm ERR!   code: 'EACCES',
npm ERR!   syscall: 'mkdir',
npm ERR!   path: '/usr/local/lib/node_modules/lite-server'
npm ERR! }
npm ERR!
npm ERR! The operation was rejected by your operating system.
npm ERR! It is likely you do not have the permissions to access this file as the current user
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you believe this might be a permissions issue, please double-check the
npm ERR! permissions of the file and its containing directories, or try running
npm ERR! the command again as root/Administrator.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/abdulfattahsheu/.npm/_logs/2022-03-22T14_26_56_457Z-debug-

above is the error it keeps giving me

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try this commands line

```
npm install -g npm-windows-upgrade
npm install -g concurrently
npm install lite-server@2.3 --save-dev
```